# How to write Unit test case for @async function?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I want to write a test case for an async function which uses @async annotation of spring framework. When I run the test case it executes by a main thread instead of multiple threads. I want to run async function by multiple threads.

I wrote the test case by using jmockit. When I run the test case it executes by the main thread.

```
Test Case:
  @Test
  public void applyOffers_ValidRequest_Success() {

    final QuoteDetailBO quotesToBeProcessed = prepareQuoteDetailRequest();
    new Expectations() {
      {
        grpOfferService.processOffer((QuoteDetailBO) any);
      }
      {
        cpOfferService.processOffer((QuoteDetailBO) any);
      }
    };

    final List<CompletableFuture<Void>> appliedOffers = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream().forEach(i -> {
      appliedOffers.add(asyncCPGrpService.applyOffers(quotesToBeProcessed));
    });
    if (CompletableFuture.allOf(appliedOffers.toArray(new CompletableFuture[appliedOffers.size()]))
        .isDone()) {
      assertEquals(appliedOffers.size(), 3);
    }

  }

Code:

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<Void> applyOffers(QuoteDetailBO quotesToBeProcessed) {
    log.info("Calling GRP and CP for {}", quotesToBeProcessed);
    grpOfferService.processOffer(quotesToBeProcessed);
    cpOfferService.processOffer(quotesToBeProcessed);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
  }
```

I want to test that async function is running with multiple threads.

Comment: That would be an integration test, not a unit test. And it would test that Spring works as expected, not that your method does what it's supposed to do. Is it really useful?

Comment: it is not useful because it only hit the rest points by using feign client. So you mean to say it can be done by integration test only. As I understand because in the unit test case we don't have context up so we can't test.